VS code server for wsl closed unexpectedly！！！ how can I do
the problem happened at today，yesterday was no problem……
the messages show in the terminal are as follow：
[2024-04-18 09:46:52.636] Extension version: 0.88.0
[2024-04-18 09:46:52.637] L10N bundle: undefined
[2024-04-18 09:46:52.687] authorityHierarchy: wsl+ubuntu-18.04
[2024-04-18 09:46:52.687] WSL extension activating for a local WSL instance
[2024-04-18 09:46:52.708] Resolving wsl+ubuntu-18.04, resolveAttempt: 1
[2024-04-18 09:46:52.709] WSL feature installed: true (dll path)
[2024-04-18 09:46:52.709] NodeExecServer run: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe --list --verbose
[2024-04-18 09:46:52.946] 4 distros found
[2024-04-18 09:46:52.947] Starting VS Code Server inside WSL (wsl2)
[2024-04-18 09:46:52.947] Windows build: 19045. Multi distro support: available. WSL path support: enabled
[2024-04-18 09:46:52.947] Scriptless setup: false
[2024-04-18 09:46:52.947] No shell environment set or found for current distro.
[2024-04-18 09:46:53.195] WSL daemon log file: 
[2024-04-18 09:46:53.199] Probing if server is already installed: if [ -d ~/.vscode-server/bin/e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39 ]; then printf 'install-found '; fi; if [ -f /etc/alpine-release ]; then printf 'alpine-'; fi; if [ -s ~/.vscode-server/bin/compatibilty-check ]; then printf 'legacy-'; fi; uname -m;
[2024-04-18 09:46:53.200] NodeExecServer run: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-18.04 -e sh -c if [ -d ~/.vscode-server/bin/e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39 ]; then printf 'install-found '; fi; if [ -f /etc/alpine-release ]; then printf 'alpine-'; fi; if [ -s ~/.vscode-server/bin/compatibilty-check ]; then printf 'legacy-'; fi; uname -m;
[2024-04-18 09:46:53.669] Probing result: install-found x86_64
[2024-04-18 09:46:53.669] Server install found in WSL
[2024-04-18 09:46:53.669] NodeExecServer run: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-18.04 sh -c '"$VSCODE_WSL_EXT_LOCATION/scripts/wslServer.sh" e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39 stable code-server .vscode-server --host=127.0.0.1 --port=0 --connection-token=3028454634-2925020714-1853595799-3364984376 --use-host-proxy --without-browser-env-var --disable-websocket-compression --accept-server-license-terms --telemetry-level=all'
[2024-04-18 09:46:54.512] Setting up server environment: Looking for /root/.vscode-server/server-env-setup. Not found.
[2024-04-18 09:46:54.512] WSL version: 5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 Ubuntu-18.04
[2024-04-18 09:46:54.512] WSL-shell-PID: 2232
[2024-04-18 09:46:54.512] Node executable: /root/.vscode-server/bin/e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39/node
[2024-04-18 09:46:54.512] Starting server: /root/.vscode-server/bin/e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39/bin/code-server --host=127.0.0.1 --port=0 --connection-token=3028454634-2925020714-1853595799-3364984376 --use-host-proxy --without-browser-env-var --disable-websocket-compression --accept-server-license-terms --telemetry-level=all
[2024-04-18 09:46:54.512] /root/.vscode-server/bin/e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39/node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /root/.vscode-server/bin/e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39/node)
[2024-04-18 09:46:54.512] For help with startup problems, go to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_wsl-tips
[2024-04-18 09:46:54.515] NodeExecServer run: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-18.04 -e kill 2232
[2024-04-18 09:46:58.696] Download in background is enabled

I try to run “code .” in the command windows, and failed:
root@DESKTOP-BV6FQSE:~# code .
/mnt/c/Users/Bourbon/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.88.0/scripts/wslCode.sh: 68: /mnt/c/Users/Bourbon/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.88.0/scripts/wslCode.sh: /root/.vscode/bin/2213894ea0415ee8c85c5eea0d0ff81ecc191529/bin/remote-cli/code: not found


I had the same problem today and i found your question
This is what worked for me.
Inside the wsl prompt, I used this command to delete the .vscode-server
sudo rm -rf ~/.vscode-server

I then reinstalled vs code remote using this command.
code .

Hope it works for you too
